# ZyXEL old devices firmware compression method

Tags: decompress

I have bumped into a compression format which `binwalk` doesn't seem able to identify. It is used in at least ZyXEL P-724 firmware images. Running `file` doesn't show anything.

Comparing the files I have, I found there seems to be a fixed-size header of around 20 bytes (checked with two files drastically different in both size and contents -- namely, `HTPCode` and `RasCode`). Poking around `BootExt` I can see decompression-related string, but nothing that would give away the exact algorithm.

The suspected header bytes are (bytes that differ marked out):

`08 00 xx xx 71 A8 1A xx 17 2A 7C 60 xx C2 02 0C 20 83 10 00`

A sample containing the original image, extracted ROM object, and the compressed data itself: https://yadi.sk/d/lBRqhldYjRMPf

Comment: Link that you provided does not seam to work right now

Comment: Perhaps try dev-zzo/router-tools. Worked for me for some old Zyxel firmwares....